# Is $0$ element of a multiplicative set

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given a multiplicative system $S\subset A$, where $A$ is a ring,one defines an equivalence relation on $A \times S$ by $(a,s)\sim(b,t) \Leftrightarrow (at - bs)u = 0$ for some $u\in S.$ Hence one does not exclude that $0\in S.$ In that case $u=0$ would work for any such pairs. Thus, I am wondering if $0\in S$ holds since it is not said neither in the definition of the multiplicative set $S$ nor in the definition of the equivalence relation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Either $0\in S$, or $0\not\in S$. I'm not sure I understand the question. As you observe, if $0\in S$, then $S^{-1}A$ is the zero ring.

Comment: You choose the set $S$. If you include $0$ in $S$ you end up with an uninteresting equivalence realtion (and assuming you are using it for this an uninteresting ring of fractions). Therefore you normally only consider $S$ without $0$

Comment: The definition I know allows for $0$ to be in a multiplicative set, though it's usually not going be the case, and it mandates that $1\in S$.

Comment: In summary: $0\in S$ is just the trivial case and therefore is just often not considered. So your question is somehow only about the trivial case, to include it or not.